# Bash URL not working with youtube-dl

Tags: bash

So, until recently i could execute commands without a problem in my Terminal.
Example:

> $ youtube-dl COMMAND
>
> done

all is well.

Now i am experiencing strange behaviour form job control, and it looks like an extra process is getting ran every time i am running something.

Example:

> Ice$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgjkth6BRRY&index=14&list=PL05E1623111A9A860
>
> [1] 3535
>
> [2] 3536
>
> [2]+  Done                    index=14
>
> Ice$ [youtube] Kgjkth6BRRY: Downloading webpage
>   [youtube] Kgjkth6BRRY: Downloading video info webpage
>
> ****At This point i am forced to press Enter to finish my command which i have never done before******
>
> [1]+  Done                    youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kgjkth6BRRY
>   Ice$

How, do i verify what the Proccess are and how would i go about fixing this?

Comment: put the URL inside single quotes.

Comment: I have tried this and it works, would there be any particular reason this has changed, as before the quotes were not required and everything worked perfectly? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the URL inside single quotes to preserve the contents inside the quotes. Note that Character like `&`, `$` has special meaning in bash and bash try to interpret them.  To prevent this from happening use single quotes.

Here: Your URL contains `&` and it means to send any command to the background.

Comment: That answers the whole ordeal very nicely, tested this function with a non-"&" input and it worked normally!